# Can't see my project's strings in Django Rosetta

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

I have installed and configured `rosetta` on my `Django` project and I can say it is working because I can see multi-language features with `Django admin` and I can see strings to translate in `third party` and `django` tabs, but when a chose `project` tab I get this message:

```
Nothing to translate!
You haven't specified any languages in your settings file, or haven't yet generated a batch of translation catalogs.

Please refer to Django's I18N documentation for a guide on how to set up internationalization for your project.
```

I have already used `gettext()` in my code but I can't see those strings in `rosetta`.

This is an example of the use of `gettext()` in my `models.py`:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class Hotel(models.Model):

    ONE_STAR = '*'
    TWO_STARS = '**'
    THREE_STARS = '***'
    FOUR_STARS = '****'
    FIVE_STARS = '****'
    GRAND_TOURISM = 'GRAND_TOURISM'
    NA = 'NA'
    SPECIAL = 'SPECIAL'
    ECO = 'ECO'
    BOUTIQUE = 'BOUTIQUE'

    HOTEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (ONE_STAR, _('*')),
        (TWO_STARS, _('**')),
        (THREE_STARS, _('***')),
        (FOUR_STARS, _('****')),
        (FIVE_STARS, _('*****')),
        (GRAND_TOURISM, _('Grand Tourism')),
        (NA, _('NA')),
        (SPECIAL, _('Special')),
        (ECO, _('Eco-Hotel')),
        (BOUTIQUE, _('Boutique-Hotel'))
    )
```

This is the configuration of languages in `settings.py`:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]    

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('de', gettext('German')),
    ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
)

USE_I18N = True
```

I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: I could solve the problem I reported, it was just that I was using the wrong language code when using `makemessages`, but now I only can see the translation strings in the `settings.py`, and I can't see the translation strings in other applications. `makemessages` created all the `*.po` files in the directory for every django application, but rosetta seems not to notice about them.

Comment: Ok, they finally showed in the `Third party` tab, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Developers should know that when you are adding a language's region or specific written script form, your command for making the messages must use "_" (underscore) as the region separator and your project's `settings.py` must use the "-" (hyphen) as the region separator.

For example, let's say we are adding the "UK" version of English, both Traditional and Simplified Chinese, and the Hong Kong region for Chinese (Cantonese).  Here are the commands to create the language translation files:

```
$ django-admin makemessages -l en_uk
$ django-admin makemessages -l zh_hk
$ django-admin makemessages -l zh_hans
$ django-admin makemessages -l zh_hant
```

And the project's `settings.py` needs the LANGUAGES tuple to contain them using the hyphen:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-uk', _('English (UK)')),
    ('zh-hk', _('Cantonese')),
    ('zh-hans', _('Chinese (Simplified)')),
    ('zh-hant', _('Chinese (Traditional)')),
)
```